Is it possible to create a Flutter app that blurs the entire screen (desktop, tablet, or phone) including other apps?
I’m inspired by a discussion on Threads where users considered the idea of an app to assist senior citizens by blurring the screen of their devices. The concept was to blur everything on the screen—desktop, tablet, or phone — with a slider to adjust the level of blur, so users wouldn’t need glasses.
I initially thought Flutter could help achieve this. I tried using the fl_pip package, which supports Picture-in-Picture mode. While it allows creating a semi-transparent floating widget, it doesn’t actually blur the entire screen, and it only works on Android and iOS. Other packages I found had even more limited functionality.
After extensive exploration, I’m leaning toward the conclusion that this functionality—blurring the entire screen, including other apps and system elements—is impossible to achieve with Flutter due to platform restrictions.
So, my question is:

Is it indeed impossible to create an app (Flutter or otherwise) that applies a blur effect over the entire screen, including other apps, on Android, iOS, or desktop platforms?

If it is possible, could you provide guidance or alternatives for implementing this functionality?



Its impossible on iOS no matter what development environment or tool you use.

Android devices support screen effects - tweaking beyond you could thought of through "Display over other apps" feature & accessibility service. Several apps demonstrate this capability, such as the "Darker" app, which allows users to reduce screen brightness below the system's minimum level - similar to the Extra Dim feature found in Pixel phones. This accessibility service and overlay effects are versatile enough that some apps even use it to create visual effects, like simulating a cracked screen display and possibly blur effects also. So implementing additional screen blur functionality is definitely possible on Android devices, but for other platforms its not possible to do such thing, don't even think of iOS or macOS as paulw11 said. It might be possible for desktops ( windows + Linux ) but for that you must have deep understanding of display managers and window managers in Linux, windows.
You can find code from these kind of apps if they are available on Github.
Projects that i found:

lowbrightness
screen-filter


Thanks for the detailed response! My question specifically targets achieving a "blur" effect across the screen, not dimming or brightness adjustments. While the examples you provided highlight interesting uses of overlays, they address a different issue. If you’re aware of ways to achieve a blur effect—either through Android’s accessibility services, overlays, or any other method—I’d greatly appreciate that insight. Alternatively, if it’s entirely unfeasible, a detailed explanation of why would still be helpful for clarification. Thank you!
